# Get all items of a certain type from a List of abstract type

Tags: c#

I have a `List<>` of abstract objects that contains different types of objects. 
I am trying to grab **all the items of a certain type** and set those items to their own `List<>`.

This is not working -

```
//myAbstractItems is a List<myAbstractItem>
//typeAList inherents from myAbstractItem


var typeAList = ((List<itemTypeA>)myAbstractItems.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(itemTypeA)).ToList());
```

The casting `(List<itemTypeA>)` appears to be failing.

Comment: Is it important if you get elements of type `itemTypeA` _or a derived type_ or get elements of `itemTypeA` _exactly_?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`OfType` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var typeAList = myAbstractItems.OfType<itemTypeA>().ToList();
```

From the documentation...

> The OfType(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in *source* that can be cast to type *TResult*.

Comment: Just for completeness, this solution has the following (good) properties: **(1)** Elements of a type _derived_ from `itemTypeA` are also included in the new list. (Here `itemTypeA` is known to be a `class` type. Had it been a generic interface type, generic delegate type, or array type, co- and/or contravariance would also be considered.) **(2)** Any `null` entries have no run-time type are _not_ included in the new list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Where` this way:

```
var typeAList = myAbstractItems.Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(itemTypeA)).Select(item => item as itemTypeA).ToList())
```

Comment: Instead of the last `Select` you _could_ also do a `.Cast<itemTypeA>()`.

Answer (score 0):

A good old loop should be fine :

```
List<itemTypeA> res = new List<itemTypeA>();
foreach(var item in myAbstractItems)
{
  itemTypeA temp = item as itemTypeA;
  if (temp != null)
    res.Add(temp)
}
```

Comment: This is subtly different from the (attempted) original code in that it will return anything that can be assigned as `itemTypeA`, rather than only things of that *exact* type.

Comment: You are right but the code and the question are ambiguous in the question ^^

Comment: Yes, apologies, I meant to add in my comment that your version could well be what OP *wants* :p

Answer (score 0):

This will work for all `itemTypeA`s (and more derived types).

```
var typeAList = myAbstractItems.Select(i => i as itemTypeA).Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

EDIT: edited as per Rawling's comment.

Comment: Why not put the `Select` before the `Where` and not perform the `as` cast twice?

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this is using the OfType() method:

```
var typeAList = myAbstractItems.OfType<itemTypeA>().ToList();
```

This method basically performs the following operation:

```
var typeAList = myAbstractItems.Where(i=>i is itemTypeA).Select(i=>i as itemTypeA).ToList();
```

Keep in mind that this will fail if any element of the source collection is a null reference.

Comment: The last example would give a `List<TheAbstractType>`, not a `List<itemTypeA>`, that's what the Original Poster is talking about. Interesting to remember what happens to `null` items, though.